# What's best way to make rails flash entries persist until the next action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've put some code like this

```
flash[:task_loader] = flash[:task_loader]
flash[:task_loader_params] = flash[:task_loader_params]
```

in a function in my controller which all my actions can call.  This has the effect of keeping those two flash entries in the `FlashHash`.  (I presume this rather odd-looking code works because the '=' does more than just assign values.)

My question is, is there a better way to do this?  Something like

```
flash[:task_loader].pin
```

Comment: I would like to know as well, and I could not get your 1st solution to work either ? i am not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash is a convenient wrapper for storing data in cookies and expiring them in the next request. So that your notification messages will work through 2 (or multiple) request response cycles.

If you want some more persistence, you can use session:

```
session[:task_loader] = my_task_loader
```

Note that one cookie can hold only 4KB of data.

> (I presume odd-looking code works
>   because the '=' does more than just
>   assign values.)

This is because it is not simply an assignment, but a method `[]=`, with a signature similar to this:

```
def []=(k, v)
```

Comment: I'm using the flash in this case to store information on what to load when an AJAX request is made to reload a list of items on the current page.  I can't user the session - my app gets confused when making AJAX calls from pages drawn from the browser's history.